# Scrape data that is not in the source code, using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape whole div from one website. The data is not visible in the source code, it changes based on the variable in the URL ([link](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures.jsp?Lang=en&SimDate=20190329&Area=&MeasType=&StartPub=&EndPub=&MeasText=&GoodsText=&op=&Taric=2103909010&search_text=goods&textSearch=&LangDescr=pl&OrderNum=&Regulation=&measStartDat=&measEndDat=)).

I was looking for any solution to copy to the excel sheet everything from

```
<div id="div_measures_for_2103909010" class="measures_detail">
```

Unfortunately since there is no data in direct source code I have found a way to display only data from the div provided above [Link](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures_details.jsp?Lang=en&Taric=2103909010&EndPub=&Domain=TARIC&op=&MeasText=&Offset=0&Area=&ShowMatchingGoods=&callbackuri=CBU-12&LangDescr=&Regulation=&MeasType=&textSearch=&SimDate=20190329&StartPub=&measStartDat=&OrderNum=&GoodsText=&search_text=goods&ExpandAll=&measEndDat=&Sid=eJwtUcmRxEAIS6gfiENA%2fomtGO%2bLwi10OcodGS%2byy1EvtOfMcysfyxcWad6aO9ard0YstXOs6rdba5LeaS8CaGqC1SGe1ta6h7MBvS8m%2btOzPnx54PlU%2bH76K11fXffHY6nvuRWje2d58XRppkmxUO8xFOSBlrN%2b%2b8jI8S13P329f7z4co1y1w7OB%2bX%2bfBOcy%2bumQ%2flfXOD%2fHOI7I1Av3gKOfBHudT7Bu79ejj%2fXsP2vJ5xvInE41uX0oJV0yhYen59ff78LTdUq3YiOan%2fTPBi6x6l6hlUHy7Y9epVr2QeLaznngj2sftulRBkLp9Z%2bLpgyOO8PwzVmEg%3d%3d&FrameId=taric_2103909010_1553859343329)

However to get this data I would need at first get the link to the direct data (the link is in the source code).

Do you have any idea how to deal with it the best possible way?

I've tried to download the source code, search for the link, open the link and copy all the data, but I have troubles downloading the source code (excel downloads only part of it due to cell data limitations). Here is my current code:

```
Sub Open_Webpage()

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures.jsp?Lang=en&SimDate=20190329&Area=&MeasType=&StartPub=&EndPub=&MeasText=&GoodsText=&op=&Taric=2103909010&search_text=goods&textSearch=&LangDescr=pl&OrderNum=&Regulation=&measStartDat=&measEndDat="
objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send ("")
html = objHTTP.responseText
Range("A1").Value = html

End Sub
```

If I am able to have full code in one cell I can then look for the link in the source code and use it:

```
=MID(LEFT(A1,FIND("' width='100%'",A1)-1),FIND("' src='",A1)+7,LEN(A1))
```

I know that there must be some better solution, but I'm not so proficient in VBA to figure it out...

Comment: `split(split(a1," width='100%'")(1)," src=")(0)`  might be a way of looking.

Comment: I cannot split the data in A1 since there is no full source code, only part of it (the part  that is max number of characters that can be stored in a cell)

Comment: Instead of A1, use the response text

Answer (score 1):

You can regex out the required url, do a little cleaning then pass on to xhr. For some reason I was unable to simply use `getAttribute("onclick")` so had to use `outerHTML` (`innerHTML` also fine) on the element

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, s As String, re As Object, url As String
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument                  '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures.jsp?Lang=en&SimDate=20190329&Area=&MeasType=&StartPub=&EndPub=&MeasText=&GoodsText=&op=&Taric=2103909010&search_text=goods&textSearch=&LangDescr=pl&OrderNum=&Regulation=&measStartDat=&measEndDat=", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

        s = html.querySelector("[id$='_end_goods']").outerHTML
        With re
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = "measures_details\.jsp(.*)'\);"
            If .Test(s) Then
                url = "https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures_details.jsp" & .Execute(s)(0).SubMatches(0)
                url = Replace$(url, "&amp;", "&")
            End If
        End With
        If Len(url) > 0 Then
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText                
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = html.querySelector(".measures_detail").innerText
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Try the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/rcT7ZM/1)

---

**References:**

1. VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: Did this answer your question?